# Raise Alert through apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, iot

I am using Apache Spark to take real time data from Apache Kafka which are from any sensors in Json format.

example of data format :

```
{
    "meterId" : "M1",
    "meterReading" : "100"
 }
```

I want to apply rule to raise alert in real time. i.e. if I did not get data of "meter M 1" from last 2 hours or meter Reading exceed some limit the alert should be created.

so how can I achieve this in Scala?

Comment: *First thing* - As I know the json in kafka should be: one message per one line - send this instead -> `{"meterId":"M1","meterReading":"100"}`

*Second*: Create SparkStreamingContext and configure to read messages from kafka in batches.

*Third*: Implement your logic ("exceed some limit", "no data in some time" ...) with spark and write output to somewhere - place with all alerts (eg. hdfs, kafka ...)

Comment: Thanks @VladoDemcak. It will help me a lot. but want to know how can i read individual object like for meterId M1 meterReading is 100. can i parse each line coming from kafka for this?

Comment: I added answer with example in more details

Answer (score 1):

I will respond here as an answer - too long for comment.

As I said json in kafka should be: one message per one line - send this instead -> `{"meterId":"M1","meterReading":"100"}`

If you are using kafka there is KafkaUtils with that you can create stream:

`JavaPairDStream<String, String> input = KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, zkQuorum, group, topics);`

Pair means `<kafkaTopicName, JsonMessage>`. So basically you can take a look only to jsonmessage if you dont need to use kafkaTopicName.

for `input` you can use many methods that are described in [JavaPairDStream documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaPairDStream.html) - eg. you can use map to get only messages to simple JavaDStream.

And of course you can use some json parser like `gson`, `jackson` or `org.json` it depends on use cases, performance for different cases and so on.

So you need to do something like this:

```
JavaDStream<String> messagesOnly = input.map(
   new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
       public String call(Tuple2<String, String> message) {
           return message._2();
       }
   }
);
```

now you have only messages withou kafka topic name, now you can use your logic like you described in question.

```
 JavaPairDStream<String, String> alerts = messagesOnly.filter(
    new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call(Tuple2<String, String> message) {
            // here use gson parser e.g 
            // filter messages with meterReading that doesnt exceed limit
            // return true or false based on your logic
        }
    }
);
```

And here you have only alert messages - you can send it to another place.

---

***-- AFTER EDIT***

Below is the example in `scala`

```
// batch every 2 seconds
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap

def filterLogic(message: String): Boolean=
{
    // here your logic for filtering
}

// map _._2 takes your json messages
val messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)

// filtered data after filter transformation
val filtered = messages.filter(m => filterLogic(m))
```

Comment: @Nilesh In the answer I have added example for `scala`